# What is Frobenius map of an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I was reading about elliptic curves from [this PDF](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf). Page 44 defines Frobenius map. It defines the frobenius map as $f(x,y) = (x^p, y^p) \bmod p$. Isn't it just an identity map? What's the use of this map in elliptic curves?

Comment: For future reference: In SO, cross-posting on two different [sites](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021589/use-of-frobenius-map-of-an-elliptic-curve) is not a good etiquette. Select one, and give the community a chance to answer.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is defined on $E(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$, the curve over the entire algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ of $\mathbb F_p$.  Under what circumstances is $x \mapsto x^p$ the identity on a field of characteristic $p$?  [migrated from answer, pursuant to [homework hinting policy](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1117)]